# jQuery Moving Items from one list to another based on the combobox selection

Tags: jquery

I have two combobox one with all available Countries name and other is empty like:

**Countries**

```
<select name="countryId[]" multiple="multiple" id="countryId" size="10">
    <option id="" value="1" >Afghanistan</option>
    <option id="" value="3" >Albania</option>
    <option id="" value="4" >Algeria</option>
    <option id="" value="5" >American samoa</option>
</select>
```

**Empty**

```
<select name="mycountryId[]" multiple="multiple" id="mycountryId" size="10">
</select>
```

Now if I select any country from Countries list it should move to Empty list but with **selected** attribute and exact **value** some thing if I select three countries from Countries list result should be:

**Countries**

```
<select name="countryId[]" multiple="multiple" id="countryId" size="10">
    <option id="" value="1" >Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```

**Empty**

```
<select name="mycountryId[]" multiple="multiple" id="mycountryId" size="10">
    <option selected="selected" id="" value="3" >Albania</option>
    <option selected="selected" id="" value="4" >Algeria</option>
    <option selected="selected" id="" value="5" >American samoa</option>
</select>
```

and similarly if I clicked on any country from my new country list (named **Empty**) then the selected country should move back to available countries list with **un-selected** attribute and exact **value**
like
**Countries**

        Afghanistan
        Algeria

I follow [Jquery - Moving Items from one list to another based on the combobox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756703/jquery-moving-items-from-one-list-to-another-based-on-the-combobox-selection) it is very nice piece of code **but how to make all values selected which are moving in targetCars?** with **selected** attribute and vise versa?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```js
function MoveListBoxItem(leftListBoxID, rightListBoxID, isMoveAll) {
    if (isMoveAll == true) {

        $('#' + leftListBoxID + ' option').remove().appendTo('#' + rightListBoxID).removeAttr('selected');

    }
    else {

        $('#' + leftListBoxID + ' option:selected').remove().appendTo('#' + rightListBoxID).removeAttr('selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should have been the correct answer, MUCH simpler.

Answer (score 2):

First, why your are using `[]` in your control ids? you can move Items from one list to another using this,

```
      $('#countryId option:selected').appendTo('#countryId');
```

for more on operation on `select` elements [Manipulating Select options](http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/)

Comment: Thanks Furqan I just replace my jQuery with 6. Moving options from list A to list B. and it work like a wizard thanks bro.... :) A vote 4 U

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the html code!

```
        <select multiple id="countryId">
            <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="2">Albania</option>
            <option value="3">Algeria</option>
            <option value="4">American samoa</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" id="add">add &gt; &gt;</a>

        <select multiple id="mycountryId"></select>
        <a href="#" id="remove">remove &lt; &lt;</a>
```

and my javascript code.

```
$("#countryId").click(function(){
    $("#countryId option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#mycountryId"));
})
$("#mycountryId").click(function(){
    $("#mycountryId option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#countryId"));
})
```

Make sure you added `jquery.js` file to your project!